# Groupby and compare/filter particular groups depending on other column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filter, group-by

I have a df like:

```
number   city        date
1        Denver_1     2019-01-14
1        Denver_1     2019-01-15
1        Denver_1     2019-01-16
1        Denver_2     2019-03-28
1        Denver_2     2019-03-29
2        Denver_1     2019-05-14
2        Denver_1     2019-05-15
2        Denver_1     2019-05-16
2        Denver_2     2019-01-28
2        Denver_2     2019-01-29
2        Seattle      2019-03-22
2        Seattle      2019-03-22
3        Denver_2     2019-05-28
3        Denver_2     2019-05-29
3        Seattle      2019-03-21
3        Seattle      2019-03-21
```

I want to groupby **number** and select the *Denver* with the higher **date**s and leave *Seattle*s how they are because those do not duplicate like *Denver*s do.
The result I want would look like:

```
number   city        date
1        Denver_2     2019-03-28
1        Denver_2     2019-03-29
2        Denver_1     2019-05-14
2        Denver_1     2019-05-15
2        Denver_1     2019-05-16
2        Seattle      2019-03-22
2        Seattle      2019-03-22
3        Denver_2     2019-05-28
3        Denver_2     2019-05-29
3        Seattle      2019-03-21
3        Seattle      2019-03-21
```

I have tried:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['number']).apply(lambda x: x['city'].unique())

number
1       [Denver_1, Denver_2]
2       [Denver_1, Denver_2, Seattle]
```

which shows me the different cities for each number, but I don't know how to add the max date filter onto that and apply it to the main df.

Other examples I saw using groupby().filter() would get rid of *Seattle*s in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, since the rules are different I think you need to handle Denver and Seattle separately:

Load Your Sample Data:

```
s = '''number   city        date
1        Denver_1     2019-01-14
1        Denver_1     2019-01-15
1        Denver_1     2019-01-16
1        Denver_2     2019-03-28
1        Denver_2     2019-03-29
2        Denver_1     2019-05-14
2        Denver_1     2019-05-15
2        Denver_1     2019-05-16
2        Denver_2     2019-01-28
2        Denver_2     2019-01-29
2        Seattle      2019-03-22
2        Seattle      2019-03-22
3        Denver_2     2019-05-28
3        Denver_2     2019-05-29
3        Seattle      2019-03-21
3        Seattle      2019-03-21'''


df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df =df.reset_index()
```

Solution:

```
selector = lambda x: x.loc[x['city'] == x.loc[x['date'].idxmax(), 'city']]
denvers = df[df['city'].str.contains('Denver')].groupby('number', as_index=False).apply(selector)
seattles = df[df['city'].str.contains('Seattle')]

pd.concat([denvers.reset_index(level=0, drop=True), seattles], axis = 0).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
    number      city       date
3        1  Denver_2 2019-03-28
4        1  Denver_2 2019-03-29
5        2  Denver_1 2019-05-14
6        2  Denver_1 2019-05-15
7        2  Denver_1 2019-05-16
10       2   Seattle 2019-03-22
11       2   Seattle 2019-03-22
12       3  Denver_2 2019-05-28
13       3  Denver_2 2019-05-29
14       3   Seattle 2019-03-21
15       3   Seattle 2019-03-21
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, ecortazar. This works. I just want to mention for others that if you have more *city* values, you can do df[~df['city'].str.lower().str.contains('denver')] instead of seattles = df[df['city'].str.contains('Seattle')]